# Concatenate split log messages using fluent-concat-plugin for EKS cluster running Kubernetes 1.22

Tags: logging, amazon-eks, fluentd

My EKS clusters depend on Fluentd daemonsets to send log messages to ElasticSearch. Docker wraps log messages from containers, line-by-line, in JSON. It also splits log messages into 16kb chunks if they're larger than that. This causes problems when those messages are structured JSON (embedded within Docker's JSON) since they're no longer parseable.

I've tried configuring the fluent-concat-plugin to identify split messages and re-assemble them before sending these to ElasticSearch. Despite my attempts, the messages either remain split, or nothing gets sent to ES.

All my attempts use the following input configuration in their fluentd.conf:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag raw.containers.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_type string
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</source>
```

This attempt doesn't concatenate split log messages:

```
<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  use_partial_metadata true
  separator ""
</filter>
```

This causes nothing to appear in ES for any split message.

```
<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  multiline_end_regexp /\\n$/
  separator ""
</filter>
```

This blocks all processing with errors in the fluentd log indicating "logtag" isn't present in the JSON coming back from Docker.

```
<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  use_partial_cri_logtag true
  partial_cri_logtag_key logtag
  partial_cri_stream_key stream
  separator ""
</filter>
```

How should fluent-plugin-concat, or for that matter, fluentd in general, be configured to re-assemble these split log messages before further processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a answer for you but you will not like it.

First things first...

These two options do not work because it is not an option for kubernetes. These two work only with pure docker / docker swarm. But you are using kubernetes in EKS 1.22 (I suppose that you have default runtime environment containerd on background).

```
<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  use_partial_metadata true
  separator ""
</filter>

<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  multiline_end_regexp /\\n$/
  separator ""
</filter>
```

This one should work, but it will work only if you change your runtime environment from containerd to CRI-O. Because only CRI-O runtime environment adds flag "F" / "P" in kubernetes to your logs. This flag is necessary for merging logs by logtag feature.

```
<filter raw.containers.**>
  @type concat
  key log
  use_partial_cri_logtag true
  partial_cri_logtag_key logtag
  partial_cri_stream_key stream
  separator ""
</filter>
```

Long story short: If you want to merge logs in k8s cluster which were splitted by docker because of max size 16kb, you need to use CRI-O container runtime inside k8s cluster and use logtag setup in fluentd.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion only recently when AWS moved EKS to containerd. Thanks for answering, since I had forgotten to do so here.

Answer (score 0):

The correct configuration should be

```
<filter **>
    @type concat
    key log
    stream_identity_key stream
    multiline_end_regexp /\n$/
    separator ""
</filter>
```

with a single backslash in regexp. It worked for me until upgrading EKS to 1.22, but after the upgrade only the second part of the message (which as you say doesn't contain a valid json) is sent to elasticsearch.

**Update**:

I've found that my problem it's not the kubernetes version, it's the presence in configuration of the detect_exceptions filter, that seem to break things if the second part of the message contains, e.g., the string *Exception:*